# Receiving build error in Appcelerator when compiling in xcode 8.2

Tags: xcode, appcelerator

I just installed appcelerator and when I build the default app.js that is included with a default mobile project xcode throws error and can't compile. Am I missing some configuration? I upgraded from xcode 7.4 to 8.2 and I received the same error.

Comment: Please post the compile error also.

Comment: ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :   CompileC build/Intermediates/FaveBooks.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FaveBooks.build/Objects-normal/i386/MediaModule.o Classes/MediaModule.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
[ERROR] :  (1 failure)

Comment: Hi, Is this a default '**Hello world**' project or some other project, if it some other project the please let me know modules you are using and also post the `tiapp.xml`.